# "A fatal error occurred: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed"

Tags: forms, 8, ajax

I'm implementing a form using the Drupal form and AJAX. I've done this many times before, but now I stumble upon a problem I never seen before.

My AJAX event is called when the value of a textfield is changed.

```
'#ajax' => array(
   'callback' => array($this, 'ajaxRenderSheets'),
   'event' => 'change',
),
```

In my callback I refresh the form:

```
  public function ajaxRenderSheets(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#wrapper', $form['sheets-wrapper']));

    return $response;
  }
```

Then in my form, I check if the value of a field is filled out; if so, I execute a request to google sheets API (this form state value is filled out after the ajax request. So when the texfield above is filled out, this code gets executed).

```
  if ($spreadsheet_id = $form_state->getValue('spreadsheet')) {
    $spreadsheet_info = $this->googleManager->getSpreadsheet($spreadsheet_id);
  }
```

When that request is executed I get the error:

> A fatal error occurred: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Is this a Drupal core issue, or is this related to my code?

Comment: There was a related Drupal core issue about some classes that couldn't be serialized. I think that was resolved though. Do you know where you're using a closure?

Comment: I think an exception is being thrown in code and it's trying to serialize a back trace that has a Closure in it. This might show up in your PHP error logs so you can see what is going on.

Comment: The error is thrown when I execute a call defined in this class: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/Sheets.php. For example "$this->spreadsheetService->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheet_id)". I commented out all my exception handling, and still I get this error

Comment: Ran in to this to day after a while of trial and erro found batch stores full form state , if using in a form and if you have custom objects like $form_state->set('b', $some_object);  the normal "serialize" function is not up to the task. but i agree core could do better to tell the error.

Answer (score -1):

You might try adding `use DependencySerializationTrait;` to the class.